# Server connection and read/write value

Tags: python, jquery, python-3.x

I want to read write value from a PLC through API (RESTful like) provide by constructor.

First step is authentification
Ajax code

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://192.168.10.11/sdcard/cpt/app/signin.php",
type: 'POST', dataType: 'json',data: {
'user[name]': 'admin',
'user[password]': 'hellocpt'
}
}).done(function(data) {
console.debug("signin done");
});
```

Next I can read value from JSON

```
var url='http://192.168.10.11/sdcard/cpt/app/data_api.php?
url=/app/objects/EasyIO/Ramp.out';
$.ajax(
{url: url, type: 'GET', dataType: 'json'}
).done(function(data) {console.debug(data);});
```

Response

```
{
"response" : {
"resultCode" : 0, // '0' for success, other numbers for
failure
"data" : [ // sedona object data is orgnized in list
{ // every object's data is a dictionary
"path" : "/EasyIO/Ramp", //sedona object's path
"slots" : [ //slots data is organized as a list
{
"value" : "49.000000", // 'out' slot's value
"slotType" : "property", // this slot is a
property
"name" : "out", // slot's name"type" : "float" // slot value's data type
}
]
}
]
}
}
```

Commande

```
var url = 'http://192.168.10.11/sdcard/cpt/app/data_api.php';
$.ajax({url: url,
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: {
path: '/app/objects/EasyIO/WriteIn.in',
type: 'int',
value: '100',
slotType: 'property'
}
}).done(function(data) {
console.debug(data);
});
```

Response

```
{
"response" : {
"resultCode" : 0, // '0' for success, other numbers for
failure
"value" : "100", // slot value has been changed to '100'
"type" : "int", // slot data type is 'int'
"path" : "/app/objects/EasyIO/WriteIn.in" //slot's path
}
}
```

This API [documentation](http://gofile.me/32wEs/Tvt9NOMt5)

This my python3 code test

```
import os
import requests
import pycurl
import json
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen


headers = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

data = [
  ('user[name]', 'admin'),
  ('user[password]', 'hellocpt'),
]

response = requests.post('http://192.168.0.230/sdcard/cpt/app/signin.php', headers=headers, data=data)
print("Code Status du POST: ",response.status_code)
print(response.content)


cookies = {
}

params = (
    ('url', '/app/objects/EasyIO/Ramp.out'),
)

responseget = requests.get('http://192.168.0.230/sdcard/cpt/app/data_api.php', headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies)
print("\n\nCode Status du GET: ",responseget.status_code)
print(responseget.content)
```

and my output

```
    Code Status du POST:  200
b'{"redirectUrl": "http://192.168.0.230/sdcard/cpt/dashboard/index.php" }'


Code Status du GET:  200
b'{"redirect": "http://192.168.0.230/sdcard/cpt/app/signin.php"}'
```

My problem is I don't understand why my POST command working but when I make a GET command I see redirection to signin page link. Why there is a logout?

Anyone can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you are sending your second request (GET), how will the server know that you have signed in before? The server sends you back something in the first request which you should send back to the server in your second request so the server can authenticate you.

I wasn't able to find out how your API is working using the ajax codes you have posted because the returned data is not shown in the first request but if we assume that the authentication is cookie based then instead of an empty cookie you should replace this line :

```
cookies = {
}
```

with this :

```
cookies = response.cookies
```

But this is only an example, your API might return a token instead of using cookies or some other type of authentication which is specified in the documentation.

EDIT : I was able to open the pdf file which contains the API documentation and it seems that the authentication is cookie based so the solution should work.